# Is there an option for pytest to ignore the setup.cfg file?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a `setup.cfg` file that specifies default parameters to use for `pytest`. While this is great for running tests on my whole package, I'd like to be able to ignore the `setup.cfg` options when running tests on individual modules. Is there a way to easily do this?

Answer (score 17):

This seems to do the trick on systems where `/dev/null` exists.

```
pytest -c /dev/null specific/test/location
```

`-c` tells pytest to ignore implicit configuration files and use the provided config instead. I am not sure if pytest trying to read it silently fails or considers it empty though.

Note that will not only override the location of the tests for you, but also any other configuration you may have in setup.cfg, e.g. coverage.

Answer (score 5):

You can also create an empty `pytest.ini` file in the current directory.

The config file discovery function will try to find a file matching this name first before looking for a `setup.cfg`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not ideal, but for now, I've decided to create a `runtests.py` that colleagues can use to run tests, following the suggestion in the [pytest docs](http://pytest.org/latest/goodpractices.html#create-a-pytest-standalone-script). It loses some of the features that I had wanted to keep in `setup.cfg` (but then also be able to turn off when I'm doing more targeted testing), but at least it gives me something others can use to easily run tests.

Comment: I should add that I'm still hopeful someone else will be able to provide a better answer.

Comment: Sadly, the url is dead.

Comment: So it is. It seems that their page with good practices has changed quite a bit, meaning the workaround that had existed is probably not considered good practice any more. I'll see if I can update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Updated the url - they just made a typo in its name