# How to force pytest to read options from commandline only, and ignore config files?

Tags: python, pytest

Suppose the pytest config file `pyproject.toml` is in the project directory:

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
addopts = "-rap --capture=tee-sys"
```

I usually use the options in this file when running the command `pytest`. And the options are automatically read from the file.

However, sometimes I want to run pytest with `-rA` **only**:

```
pytest -rA    # it becomes: pytest -rA --capture=tee-sys
```

I have to run it with: `pytest -rA --capture=fd` to override the option `--capture=tee-sys` in the config file.

Is there any way to **force pytest to read options from commandline only**?

**What I've tried:**

In @Andrei 's answer of this question: [Is there an option for pytest to ignore the setup.cfg file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32444402/is-there-an-option-for-pytest-to-ignore-the-setup-cfg-file)

Use `-c /dev/null` will prevent pytest from finding the config file. I also find that set `-c any-non-exist-path` is ok.

However, I'm afraid if `-c /dev/null` has **side effects**. In pytest docs (https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/customize.html#finding-the-rootdir), it says `If -c is passed in the command-line, use that as configuration file, and its directory as rootdir`. I don't know what will happen if **rootdir is set as a non exist dir**.

Comment: Could you try creating an empty `pytest.ini` file. I think this would take precedence over other configuration files.

Comment: @quamrana creating an empty `pytest.ini` file does take precedence over other configuration files. However, I'm wondering if there exists a way to keep the behaviour that when I run `pytest`, the options are read from file.

Comment: Perhaps write all the options you want into `pytest.ini`?

Comment: @quamrana If writing all options into pytest.ini, the unspecified options in commandline will still be completed by the config file pytest.ini.

Comment: But, isn't that what you want?

Comment: @quamrana No. What I want is when I run `pytest`, the options are read from file. and when I run `pytest -some-args`, the remaining args are not read from file. Thanks though.

Comment: I don't think that `pytest` will support your requirements. You could request such a feature from the maintainers. In the meantime your options are to just have a `pytest.ini` with your required configuration. (You could rename it to `xpytest.ini` to allow the pre-existing `pyproject.toml` file to take over)